# Magento 2 product detail page non cacheable

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am facing an issue with PFC and varnish for the product detail pages. I get the following:

***X-Magento-Cache-Control:max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS***

One of the blocks of that page is non cacheable

I have removed the cacheable="false" but the result is still the same.

Do you experience the same behaviour on your end? How can this be debug further?

Answer (score 0):

I end up changing the block from `cacheable=false` to `cacheable=true`, flush the cache and the cache control changed to allow the page to be cached.